# What does 'HN' mean in HN50?

Tags: optics, terminology, notation, polarization

What does the 'HN' stand for in 'HN50'? HN50 is a type of linear polarizer which reduces the power of the input by 50%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different types of polarizer materials.  The wikipedia page on [Polaroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaroid_(polarizer)) sheets names a few, but the most common is the "H" sheet.  The "H" designation comes from that.

The "N" indicates neutral color extinction.  You can find "HR" sheets which block higher frequencies (R for red) and can be used for IR work.

The number is the percentage of unpolarized light to pass through the filter.